# Why does the post-increment operator ($j++) never change $j from 0?

Tags: php, increment

I've encountered a strange problem with the increment operator.  What should the code below output?

```
$j = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++)
{
    $j = $j++;
}
echo $j;
```

It echoes 0. Why not 100?

---

Edit: When I change `$j = $j++` to `$j = ++$j`, it echoes 100.

Comment: You're using postfix increment, which will assign the value of the variable before it's incremented. So `$j` = 0 every time. `++$j` would do the incrementing before the assignment. Of course you can just skip the assignment altogether and do `$j++` by itself...

Comment: This would be a good interview question.

Comment: @Umbrella: It might be a good phone-screen question, to help you decide whether it's worth inviting a candidate on site.

Comment: @AdamLiss: An early question, yes, right up there with the FizzBuzz problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing a "post-increment", since the `++` appears AFTER the variable it's modifying. The code, written out in less compact form, boils down to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
   $temp = $j;  // store j
   $j = $j + 1;  // $j++
   $j = $temp; // pull original j out of storage
}
```

If you had `++$j`, then j would increment FIRST, and the resulting incremented value would be assigned back to J. However, such a structure makes very little sense. you can simply write out

```
 for (...) {
    $j++;
 }
```

which boils down to

```
for (...) {
   $j = $j + 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks Marc B, you Solve my confusing, the $j++ store the value first, so it change to 0 final. when use ++$j, it add the value first!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the line

```
$j = $j++;
```

This command evaluates `$j` as 0, then increments `$j` to 1, and finally does the assignment of 0 back to `$j`.

Either use `$j = $j + 1;` or just `$j++;`.

Comment: @AaronW. That would work, but it's both redundant and confusing.  My team would never allow it through a code review.

Answer (score 3):

`$j++` is post-increment: the value of the expression is `$j`, then `$j` is incremented.  So you're getting the value of j, then incrementing j, then setting j to the original value of j.